# How to define (table A/column X) according to (Table Y/column Z) in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Guys I need to make it like this:

I have two tables

**Users** table with column **name**

and

**Profiles** table with column **profilename**

I need to make it so that when user is created and name is given to a user, It also creates Profile and gives it profilename same as user's name.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a profile which belongs to the user so it'd have a user_id field.  Then use the  after_create callback and [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association)

```
class User

  has_one :profile
  after_create :make_profile

  def make_profile
    create_profile(:profilename => name)
  end

end

class Profile
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: It seems create method was depreciated or moved after rails 3.1 version :(

Comment: You can just use Profile.create(:user_id => id, :profilename => name) instead then but rails guides suggest it's not deprecated.

Comment: Yeah I tried that also but it sets profilename literally to "name", but I want it to be same as User's name
I also tried with ":name" or with "User.name" but its still same :(

Comment: Right I have just created a test app with exactly the code in my original answer and it works fine.  What version of rails are you using?  Did you put name in quote marks when running the code?  I.e. :profilename => "name" or did you use :profilename => name

Comment: Oh shit... You're right :) I did a mistake there sorry :)

and thank you very much for the help :)

Comment: No problem.  Obviously adding the quotes makes it an actual string of "name" being set.  Glad we got there in the end.